# Passing props to children in a composition model

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using composition model a, I have one parent element that have many children.
I'm wondering if it is possible to get the props of the parent element inside the children.
For now i'm passing the same props to all the component (parent and child) but I guess there is better way to do that.

Here the parent element

```
const ImageTop = ({ results, children }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <>
      <ImageBackground
        style={{ height: height * 0.25, width: "100%" }}
        source={imageToDisplay(results)}
      >
        <Pressable style={styles.blocArrow} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <Ionicons name="arrow-back-outline" size={32} color="white" />
        </Pressable>
        <TransparentsBar results={results} />
      </ImageBackground>
      <View style={{ marginLeft: 15, paddingTop: 15 }}>{children}</View>
    </>
  );
};
```

And here I'm passing components as children of the parent component :

```
const DetailsEvents = ({ route }) => {
  const [results] = useState(route.params.item);

  return (
    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      <ImageTop results={results}>
        <GenreAndTitle results={results} />
        <Address results={results} />
        <Date results={results} />
        <CTA results={results} />
        <Description results={results} />
        <OrganizedBy results={results} />
      </ImageTop>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

So as you can see I'm sending the same props  "Results" to all components which is ugly ... I'd like to send the props only to the parent  and the children get access to that props. Is there any way to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: Apart from using redux / context or something similar, you cannot pass the same prop to multiple components at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). This will remove the redundancy regarding sending same props to all those child components separately. What you will be doing is create a context having the `value` you want your application to use globally and wrap your root elements with that context's `Provider`. Then the `value` will be available to all your child components which you can access and modify with `useContext`.

Comment: Yes i know about React context but it's a bit overkill to use global state to just send one props... Beside there's a lot of boiler plate since I need to create context, pass value, import context in every children and also declare the variable (the prop) in every child as well.

Comment: Is there any way other than this? I am afraid there isn't any.